# Projecting 3D Mesh Region onto 2D Plane

Tags: visualization, mesh, projection

For vizualization purposes in a beamer presentation I would like to project a 3D MeshRegion like `ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}]]` onto a 2D plane. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply feed the 3D `BoundaryMeshRegion` into the 2D `RegionPlot`:

```
rr = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}]]
RegionPlot[rr]
```

[image]

To choose a different projection, apply a rotation, e.g. like this:

```
RegionPlot[Rotate[rr, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}]]
```

**Edit:**

Here is how I checked that this indeed does a projection onto the $xy$ plane rather than an intersection with some plane (which presumably would be at $z=0$):

First I define a polyhedron that contains a triangle parallel to the $xy$ plane but shifted so it doesn't intersect this plane.

```
region = 
 BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 0, 2}}, 
  Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}]]
```

[image]

The base is a right triangle with side lengths `2` and `1/2` adjacent to the right angle. Let's see if we can identify this in the projection:

```
RegionPlot[region, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: projection]

This is what I'd expect as the projection.

**Edit 2:**

A more pedestrian way of getting a projection (good as a sanity check) would be this:

```
Graphics[Inset[
  RegionPlot3D[rr, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.0001}, 
   PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Blue], Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}, 
   ViewPoint -> Top], Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]
```

[image]

This outline agrees with the projection obtained from `RegionPlot` above. The way I did this is to squish the three-dimensional output of `RegionPlot3D` by reducing the side length of the `z` dimension to nearly zero in `BoxRatios`. To create a 2D `Graphics` out of this squished 3D object, I use an `Inset`.

Comment: Does this really give an (orthogonal) projection? After Reading about [RegionPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html), I actually don't understand how this works (e.g., on which plane does it project?). Could it be, that this instead gives the intersection of the convex hull with some plane?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it does provide the projection onto the $xy$ plane by dropping the $z$ coordinate. I'll edit the answer to show how I've tested that...