# Projecting a 3D mesh region to 2D

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

How do I project a 3D `MeshRegion` to a 2D `MeshRegion` (or equivalent for a BoundaryMeshRegion). This question is similar to [Projecting 3D Mesh Region onto 2D Plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178356/projecting-3d-mesh-region-onto-2d-plane) but different because I would like to obtain the 2D `MeshRegion`, not just a plot. (I would like to be able to use RegionMember on the result for example.)

Comment: More details needed. What is the `RegionDimension` of the 3D `MeshRegion`? My point is that planar `MeshRegions` with `Tetrahedron` elements will throw an error. Maybe you need only the projection of the `RegionBoundary`?

Comment: In this case I need it for objects with `RegionDimension` `2`, so indeed the projection of the RegionBoundary would be fine. (Due to: 
`If RegionDimension[reg]<RegionEmbeddingDimension[reg]` then `RegionBoundary[reg]==reg.`)
(Otherwise the boundary of a boundary is of course the empty set.)
Although I am also interested in the more general case of a filled 3D shape. I would have thought that these two cases were quite similar anyway.

Comment: Well, things turned out to be more complicated than you thought. That happens. ;) Please give a concrete minimal example to work with.

Comment: The example in the linked question is fine. I will add it here too. The question and required output are the same except I want to obtain the MeshRegion describing the area shown in the plot in the answer to that question.

Comment: Well you can simply extract the `MeshCoordinates`, project them (optaining a point list `projpts`), and create a new `MeshRegion` with `MeshRegion[projpts, MeshCells[oldregion, 2]]`.

Comment: Thanks! I see that my actual case is actually more difficult than I thought. Indeed for the minimal example the method that I think you proposed does work:
`projpts=MeshCoordinates[reg][[All, {1, 2}]];
MeshRegion[projpts, MeshCells[reg, 2]]`.

However, in reality I am interested in projecting a concave 3D shape. And the same procedure fails there for an unknown reason, giving an error: "Degenerate cells including Polygon[{90,133,89}] have been removed".

The projection is (approximately) convex so an acceptable solution for now is: `ConvexHullMesh[MeshCoordinates[reg][[All, {1, 2}]]]`.

Comment: Shame on `MeshRegion`. It performs just too many checks during construction. This is also why the thing won't work for meshes with `Tetrahedron`. I would have implemented that data type differently. Well, nobody asked me and now I am out of ideas. ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, well that's not quite true ;-) I did ask you to join WRI a while back but I still have not seen your application! :-P

Comment: maybe `RegionUnion @@ Drop[MeshPrimitives[reg, 2], None, None, None, -1]`?